# Sitecore 6.6 vertical scroll bar issue in IE 10

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

We are facing browser compatibility issues for Sitecore_6.6.0_rev._130529 (Update -6) for browser Mode: IE 10, Document Mode: Quicker

Issue Details: Open Sitecore in content Editor Mode and go to workbox, even if it has more than 6-7 items vertical scrollbars will not be visible.

Does anyone got into same problem or have any hot-fix for it?

[image: Browser Details for reproducing Issue]

Comment: Did you try other rendering modes (like IE9 or IE8)? Assuming you have access to Sitecore Support, I would just contact them. They will probably be able to provide you with a hotfix.

Comment: IE 10 is supported in you Sitecore version, so you should not have any issues. As @RuudvanFalier said I would create a Sitecore ticket and ask them for a hotfix.

Comment: @RuudvanFalier: Thanks for pitching in. This is working fine on Other IE version. I don't have Sitecore support details but I am trying to find hot-fix for this. But no luck as now.

Comment: @KevinBrechbühl: Thanks, it would be appreciated.

Comment: I think Kevin meant **you** should create a ticket: http://support.sitecore.net

Comment: I understand that but as I written in my previous comments that I don't have support credentials details that's why I want help from @KevinBrechbühl.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm allowed to do this. Also if they will give me a hotfix assembly, I may not provide you with this code. But as you use 6.6 you work for any Sitecore partner isn't it? And I'm pretty sure you know someone in your company that is a certified developer and have access to the support portal? Anyway, I could also not reproduce your scrollbar issue, it seemes to be a problem with your CSS. Also I am in the IE 10 Compact Mode with the default document mode. If I change this, I cannot access the Content Editor at all...

Comment: @KevinBrechbühl: Please find attached screenshot for exact browser details to reproduce it. I hope this would be CSS issue only so if you could provide me hot-fix supplied CSS to me that would be okay. I am also Sitecore 7 Certified but for me Support access is not enabled. It will take time to troubleshoot this access.

Comment: This does not work for me and I also can't give you a fix for this. I have "IE10 Compat View" and "IE5 quirks" in the content editor and this works fine. I think the online solution to solve your problem is to change your settings...

Comment: Do you see any JavaScript errors?

Answer (score 0):

Adding your site to the IE trusted sites often fixes displaying issues. Have you followed the browser configuration guide from Sitecore?: [Browser configuration reference](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/browser_configuration_reference-usletter.pdf)

Comment: It was worth the try:)